# Execution Timed Out (12000 ms) : How can I fix this error

Tags: c#, .net

When i am trying to solve problem on codewars, get this error.

My code passes all the tests but not optimized . Do u have any advice ?

Problem : https://www.codewars.com/kata/525e5a1cb735154b320002c8/train/csharp

C#:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l9zt.png)

Comment: using System;

public class Kata
{
  public static int Triangular(int n)
  {
   string temp = "";
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
       for(int j = i; j <n; j++){
        if(n < 0){
            break;
           }
          else{
             temp += 1;
          }
       }
   }
   return temp.Length;
  }
}

Comment: You're getting a number and should output a number. If you were asked to multiply 10000 by 10000, would you build a 100 MB string too? Or perhaps use math? (nudge nudge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are using a brute-force solution! when you have an algorithmic/mathematics problem you should think of finding a pattern that can be represented by a formula. in this case, Triangular numbers are already a known problem and there is a solution to it, check out this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) for more details
so the solution is simple:

```
public static int Triangular(int n) 
  { 
    // handle the edge case (out-of-range values)
    if (n <= 0)
      return 0;
    
    // apply the triangular numbers formula:
    return (n * (n + 1)) / 2;
  }
```

Comment: The edge case is not required. You can't get an out-of-range value here. You can test it with negative numbers.

Comment: he is trying to solve a problem on https://www.codewars.com/kata/525e5a1cb735154b320002c8/train/csharp, if you did not set the handling of the edge case the test won't pass

Comment: Sorry, you are right, the test wants a 0 on negative inputs.

Answer (score 0):

This is pure math and does not need any strings.
Here is a single line to compute your triangular number which runs in 18ms:

```
using System;

public class Kata
{
  public static int Triangular(int n)
  {
    return n * (n + 1) / 2;
  }
}
```

This is the definition of a triangular number which maybe explains the code above:

> Tn=1+2+3+⋯+n=n⋅(n+1)2